# Pass parameter from CollectionViewController to CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to show a list of products after clicking on a category. I send the category id (rowid) to ProductListController and there I have access to rowid.

I want to send the rowid to my ProductListCell class and pass the rowid to my fetchProduct(rowid:Int) in setupViews().

Until now I have tried notificationCenter and protocol class and I could find the result I am looking for.

ProductCellList.swift

```
class ProductListCell : BaseCell ,UICollectionViewDataSource,  UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    let cellId = "cellId"
    var products = [Product]()
    weak var delegate: ProductCellDelegate?

    override func setupViews() {
        super.setupViews()

        var receivedRowId = getRowId() // here is the problem - i can't get the rowid from productlistcontroller

        fetchProduct(rowId: receivedRowId)

        addSubview(collectionView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)

        collectionView.register(ProductCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }

    func fetchProducts(rowId: Int){

        ApiServiceProduct.sharedInstance.fetchProductsList(rowId: rowId) { (products:[Product]) in
            self.products = products
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your architecture is completely wrong. In the kindest way possible, you need to find a `UICollectionView` tutorial. Search for one, there are many.

A collection view cell should not be managing its parent collection view.

A simplified overview.

[image]

- Your `ViewController` will manage a `UICollectionView` instance.
- There will be an object that adopts `UICollectionViewDatasource` protocol.
- The `ViewController` will assign that object to the `datasource` property on the collection view.
- `UICollectionView` will call `collectionView(_: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath:)` on the `datasource`
- That method will return a `UICollectionViewCell`. In your case an instance of `ProductListCell`.
- `collectionView(_: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath:)` is a good place to set the `rowID` property. A cell can be reused many times by the `dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:, for:)` method as you scroll the collection. You shouldn't assume that the `rowID` will remain the same.

Theres more to this than what I have said but it should get you started. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite follow your question, but `UICollectionView` via `UICollectionViewDelegate` has `func collectionView(UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt: IndexPath)` which is probably the ideal place to perform this task especially if the rowid and category are the same.